# Complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the complexity given for the following problem is O(n). Shouldn't it be
O(n^2)? That is because the outer loop is O(n) and inner is also O(n), therefore n*n = O(n^2)?

The answer sheet of this question states that the answer is O(n). How is that possible?

```
public static void q1d(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity for the following problem is O(n^2), how can you obtain that? Can someone please elaborate?

```
public static void q1E(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think upper one is O(n^2).and what doubt you have about second one?

Comment: This means the answer provided by my professor is incorrect hmm.

Comment: it seems that answer sheet contains errors.

Answer (score 15):

The first example is `O(n^2)`, so it seems they've made a mistake. To calculate (informally) the  second example, we can do `n * (n/2) = (n^2)/2 = O(n^2)`. If this doesn't make sense, you need to go and brush up what the meaning of something being `O(n^k)` is.

Answer (score 6):

The complexity of both code is O(n*n)

**FIRST**

The outer loop runs `n` times and the inner loop varies from `0 to n-1` times

so

`total = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + n`

which if you add the [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) is `n * ( n + 1 ) / 2` is `O(n*n)`

**SECOND**

The outer loop runs `n` times and the inner loop varies from `0 to n-1/2` times

so

`total = 1 + 1/2 + 3/2 + 4/2 ... + n/2`

which if you add the arithmetic progression is `n * ( n + 1 ) / 4` is also `O(n*n)`

Comment: So if n/2 does it still equal to o(n)? But the iteration for inner loop is half the outer loop does that make any difference?

Comment: @user1085135: `O(n)` has the meaning `linear`. It doesn't matter what constant it multiplied by, what only matters is that it **is** linear

Answer (score 2):

First case is definitely `O(n^2)`

The second is `O(n^2)` as well because you omit constants when calculate big O

Answer (score 0):

Your answer sheet is wrong, the first algorithm is clearly O(n^2).

Big-Oh notation is "worst case" so when calculating the Big-Oh value, we generally ignore multiplications / divisions by constants.

That being said, your second example is also O(n^2) in the worst case because, although the inner loop is "only" 1/2 n, the n is the clear bounding factor. In practice the second algorithm will be less than O(n^2) operations -- but Big-Oh is intended to be a "worst case" (ie. maximal bounding) measurement, so the exact number of operations is ignored in favor of focusing on how the algorithm behaves as n approaches infinity.

Comment: The second algorithm won't be less than O(n^2), it is *precisely* O(n^2). I suspect you aren't quite clear on what "O(n^2)" actually means. It means that as `n` approaches infinity, the run time increases  for the algorithm for two values of `n` is proportional to the difference between those `n` values squared.

Comment: No. In practice, the actual time complexity of the algorithm will be slightly less than O(n^2). However, because Big-Oh is a maximal bound, we say it is O(n^2). You are correct that the `n/2` factor is clearly bounded by n -- as I indicated in my answer. There are other bounding measurements (ie. Big-Theta) that compute the bounding factor differently.

Comment: Why do you think the actual time complexity of the algorithm will be less than O(n^2)? I claim it will be *precisely* O(n^2) because the algorithm's complexity *precisely* matches the *definition* of O(n^2). If it's not *exactly* O(n^2), then nothing is. We *say* it is O(n^2) because it **is** O(n^2). You seem to want to make this fuzzy, confusing, and imprecise when it is absolutely, crystal clear.

Comment: Because the actual complexity is O(n^2) + C, where C is some constant. In this case C is negative. So it will be *slightly* less than straight n^2. The C is insignificant, but you still should write the "answer" as O(n^2) - C

Comment: A complexity of `O(n^2) + C` means precisely the same thing as a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are `O(n^2)`. Your answer is wrong. Or you may have written the question incorrectly.